# Setting local time and date conversion in Python

Tags: python, django

I run the following code on the system and server and get different results

How to set the time zone to get the same result regardless of the system or server settings

```
print(datetime(2023,6,6,0,0).timestamp())
```

Comment: Is your server running a Unix system and your local machine not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the result to be in UTC:

```
import datetime
import timezone

val = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```